# How can I get this function to plot a new circle every time? I'm already using a unique key for each circle

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

```
var circleIdVal = UniqueKey();
    String cir = circleIdVal.toString();
    final CircleId circleId = CircleId(cir);
    final Circle circle = Circle(circleId: circleId);
    
    setState(() {
      circles = Set.from([
        Circle(
            circleId: CircleId(cir),
            center: LatLng(n1, n2),
            radius: n3,
            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .5),
            strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, .4))

      ]);
```

This is for a GoogleMap Widget. It plots fine but the old circle is constantly deleted and replaced with a new one.

additional info:

This is how it's called in the widget:

```
        circles: circles,
```

and how it is set:

```
  Set<Circle> circles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
setState(() {
  for (var i = 0; i < "test".length; i++) {
    var circleIdVal = UniqueKey();
    final CircleId circleId = CircleId(circleIdVal.toString());
    final Circle circle = Circle(
        circleId: circleId,
        center: LatLng(
          n1,
          n2,),
        radius: n3,
        fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .5),
        strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, .4));

    setState(() {
      circles[circleId] = circle;
    });
  }
});
    }
```